# Same data adds twice to JavaScript table instead of adding two different things to the table

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, html-table

I have a program that pulls from an API and displays the results on a table. What should be happening is that each row should be different data. However, when this runs, it adds the data with the ID of 4 twice, completely skipping over the data with the ID of 3. At first, I thought I must've goofed something up with the GET requests. I went to check, and turns out it is getting the data, but not adding it to the table. I moved all of the code to add to the table inside of the for loop, but the same problem happened. If it's any use, I'm using Tomcat to handle the API.

Attached is the function I use to add rows to the table.

````js
function addRow(tableName, rowData) {
                for (var h = 0; h < rowData.length; h++) {
                    var ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
                        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
                            if(ajaxRequest.status == 200){
                                let table = document.getElementById(tableName);
                                let row = table.insertRow(1);
                                var order = JSON.parse(ajaxRequest.responseText);
                                var cell0 = row.insertCell(0);
                                var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
                                var cell2 = row.insertCell(2);
                                var cell3 = row.insertCell(3);
                                var cell4 = row.insertCell(4);
                                var cell5 = row.insertCell(5);
                                var cell6 = row.insertCell(6);
                                var cell7 = row.insertCell(7);
                                var cell8 = row.insertCell(8);
                                var cell9 = row.insertCell(9);
                                var cell10 = row.insertCell(10);
                                
                                cell0.innerHTML = order.id;
                                cell1.innerHTML = order.name;
                                cell2.innerHTML = order.time;
                                cell3.innerHTML = order.type;
                                cell4.innerHTML = order.creamerAmount + " " + order.creamerType;
                                cell5.innerHTML = order.sugarAmount;
                                cell6.innerHTML = order.coffeeType;
                                cell7.innerHTML = order.teaType;
                                cell8.innerHTML = order.hotChocolateType;
                                cell9.innerHTML = order.smoothieType;
                                cell10.innerHTML = order.protein;
                            } else {
                                //I'm aware this is bad, not sure how to handle it otherwise though...
                                h--;
                            }
                        }           
                    }
                    ajaxRequest.open('GET', 'http://localhost:13760/cafe/cafe/orders/' + rowData[h]);
                    ajaxRequest.send();
                }
                
            }   ```
````

Comment: There's only _one_ `ajaxRequest` in your script because of [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#description). Do not use the legacy `var` and instead use `let` and `const`

Comment: And why do you send `rowData.length` requests and not just one to get them all at once?

Comment: @Andreas I forgot to mention this in the question, rowData is an array that I should probably rename that gets all of the ids for everything that needs to go on the table, getting them all at once without this caused performance problems that made the whole thing near unusable as it was attempting to do several hundred GET requests, many of which were empty, per second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Andreas is right.
Try `const ajaxRequest = ...` instead of `var ajaxRequest = ...`.

It's hard for me to explain in detail what is happening here. My guess is the following:
As said above, you use the same ajaxRequest, as if it would be declared before the for loop.
Secondly, as the request is async, it gets sent from the event loop after the main thread code is completed. Which means it sends the request to id = 4 two times.

Still I can be mistaken in the details (and please correct me if I'm wrong), but changing var to const should help. Have you tried it?

Comment: _"... if it would be declared before the for loop."_- Because this is exactly what is happening here. That's what hoisting is.

Comment: @Andreas, agree, and that is what I meant, but wasn't clear enough in my explanation. The question was, how does it act after that. I had a version that it could create the first XHR object, send the request, then create the second one and send, after which it could use the onreadystatechange of the first one and second one separately, though in the variable we refer only to the last one... Which obviously is not how it works. Of course, your answer was the first and a correct one.